# DIY Bathroom Addition Vent and Drain Questions

Tags: drain, rough-in

I am adding a bathroom addition and I need some advice on laying out the drains and vents. The new bathroom will be 8'x 15' and will be slab on grade. When the new septic system was installed a few years ago the septic contractor left me a 4" capped stub-out for connection to the future bathroom addition.

Please excuse the crude drawing, but this is what I have come up with for the layout and was hoping for a critique and advice on what may need to be adjusted. I did not attempt to draw fittings but the plan is wyes, long sweep 90s, and 45s.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], well done for your first question! What is a "VTR" that you've got labeled in your drawing? ([Edit] your post to indicate what that means.) Once you've done that, take the [tour] and browse through the [help] while you're waiting for someone to answer your question.

Comment: Vent of some sort per context, not a TLA IFW either, but gotta be a vent, and at least it does not appear to be one of those troublesome stinky AAVs...